# How does the charge on the battery terminal behave?

Tags: charge, electrical-engineering

I am sitting in a train with a car battery of of twelve volts...its positive terminal is connected through a bulb to the metallic body of the coach which is connected to the rails underneath.how will the charge on the terminal behave?Imagine the rails go all over the continent and they are electrically conductive.

Comment: What about the negative terminal?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know if any transient current would flow through the lamp, the answer is that there won't be any current to talk about.

The answer would be the same, if one terminal was just grounded, which is much simpler to arrange.

The reason is that the capacitance of the load is determined by the unconnected terminal and, therefore, is very low.